# Installing QEMU for Centos 6.6

Tags: yum, qemu, centos-6.6

6. I tried to yum install qemu and it doesn't seem to be available. How do I get QEMU onto CentOS 6.6 especially the qemu-system-* to run ISO images ?

My yum repolist:

```
repo id                    repo name                                      status
base                       CentOS-6 - Base                                6,518
extras                     CentOS-6 - Extras                                 38
rpmforge                   RHEL 6 - RPMforge.net - dag                    4,718
updates                    CentOS-6 - Updates                             1,369
repolist: 12,643
```

Answer (score 0):

[This](http://rpm.pbone.net/index.php3/stat/3/srodzaj/1/search/config(qemu-system-x86)) site has links to **qemu-system-x86-1.0-27.1.i686.rpm** & **qemu-system-x86-1.0-27.2.x86_64.rpm**

Does it help ?